# Print HTML Tables, <tr>, <td> and <a> tags on Textview Android

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I have a chat app that receives HTML as JSON through an API. Each chat message displays the HTML in a TextView, however I need to display Tables,   and  tags. I have tried with `Html.fromHtml()` function and an ImageGetter for the images, however I can't find the way to display the Table tags.

I cannot use a WebView because that would imply displaying a webview for every message (which isn't very efficient).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do formatting using the string format statement, but be aware most fonts ars scaled. You have to use tne mono-space font for this to work. –

Comment: also, html and space padding won't work together because html collapses spaces.

Answer (score 4):

`fromHtml()` does not support `<table>` and related tags. Your choices are:

1. Use WebView to render your HTML table (but as you said you don't want to do that)
2. Convert your table to text by using whitespaces or padding.
3. Natively use `TableLayout` in your Android app.